# How to solve Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\ on windows 8.1

Tags: php, xampp

I'm using windows 8.1 and I just downloaded a source code and installed Xampp and I am encountering this error

Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\plan_application\DBConnection.php on line 4

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to expand filepath in C:\xampp\htdocs\plan_application\DBConnection.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\plan_application\DBConnection.php(13): SQLite3->open('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\plan_application\DBConnection.php(85): DBConnection->__construct() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\plan_application\index.php(2): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\plan_application\DBConnection.php on line 13

Here Is what is included in the DBConnection.php from line 1 - 13

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!is_dir(__DIR__.'./db'))
    mkdir(__DIR__.'./db');
if(!defined('db_file')) define('db_file',__DIR__.'./db/plan_db.db');
function my_udf_md5($string) {
    return md5($string);
}

Class DBConnection extends SQLite3{
    protected $db;
    function __construct(){
        $this->open(db_file);
```

I got the code from the following link >> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Simple+Subscription+Website+code

I enabled all permissions to the htdocs folder read ,write modify full control but still displaying error, what could be wrong with the code?

Comment: The web server user needs write permission to that directory. Are you sure your in the correct directory.

Comment: Okay please, how do I write permission to that directory?

Comment: Open up windows explorer. Give permissions to  the user that the web server is running under. Make sure to check include sub directories if is there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you created directory Xampp by admin, but running xampp under other user who didn't have permission to this folder.
Consider changing folder permissions or alternatively give user who run Xampp permissions to this folder.

Comment: How do I change the Folder permissions by right clicking on C:\xampp folder > Properties > Security and gave all users Full control but its still giving the same Error

Comment: I think I am missing something here , or is there another way on how to change folder permissions?

Comment: Make sure you gave permissions to files and folders inside xamp folder.